# Google Search Console not showing new sitemap pages

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, xml-sitemap

I published a new sitemap on GSC and it appears that it was published successfully and that 9 pages were indexed, but when I click to see the pages, it shows me 5 pages not indexed which are the pages of the old sitemap.

Can anyone help me?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: As commented previously, we really don't troubleshoot individual sites here - see [only could apply to your site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), so please do not keep including links to your site. Questions here must be self-contained, so in this case you'd need to include a portion of your sitemap formatted as code. However, this really falls under our community wiki - see the linked question. It can take quite a while, up to several months, for Google to index or re-index your site, and additional time to update Google Search Console reports.